# With existing "mySQL Database" and "website", want to connect/synchronize both part how to accomplish by Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, web, django-models

**Main problem**: I have existing mySQL Database and website, how do I connect/synchronize  both, that input or update from mySQL, can also result in website too

I did learn HTML, CSS but was required to find the way, instead input from `<p> </p>`, need to find a way CRUD from mySQL, and result to website

after a day of research,  `python django` seems has the possiblity solve my problem, but all the tutorial is buttom up create an new website and new mySQL, **`I'm stock on connecting existing one (that the "mySQL Database" and "website")`**, that how far I reach , therefore want to ask the export in here, thanks

environment: I'm using python, window and mySQL

- the already set website screenshot
  [image: the already set website screenshot]
- the existing mySQL Database screenshot (MySQL Database, and using HeidiSQL )

[image: the existing mySQL Database screenshot]

---

the specific example:
if I update/change the context `Nordic` as `Nike` from mySQL, by success connect both, the website part the Nike can replace Nordic as new topic

[image]

---

**update** -
now I'm sure the "django" and  "MySQL" is connected

that I craete the 'TestModel' and 'TestModel_002' from django, will also added in MySQL

conclude:

- "django" and  "MySQL" is connected
- still not reach my original issue , insert/update data in "MySQL" can affect  website

https://i.stack.imgur.com/syug7.jpg

**now the "django" and "MySQL" is connected, but I'm looking for `insert/update data in "MySQL" can affect website`, seems im close, but what shall I do though?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect your django app to an existed DB, you should just edit your django `settings.py` and write this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks expert @Amin , if I just get the seperate, existed  "mySQL Database" and "website" ; which means that website also not create from django , what additionalstep should I do?

Comment: If you want to use django ORM, you should implement some models matching your DB models. @DCcon

Comment: sorry, cause I just study the django from today, do you meant `making sure DB models version can match django' version` ?

Comment: Yes! Assume that you have a table called `user` in your db. and this table has just a field called `name`. Now you are working with django and want to have your user object. So you should have a model `User`, with `name` field in it. then you can access your user via ORM like: `User.objects.get(name="some_name")`. @DCcon

Comment: thanks, at least I get the entry point to work on now, I will update result in 24hr

Comment: hi @Amin, I follow ur suggestion, now the "django" and "MySQL" is connected, but I'm looking for `insert/update data in "MySQL" can affect website`, seems im close, but what shall I do though?